# Mondrian MDX Last Element Aggregation

Tags: mdx, pentaho, data-warehouse, jasperserver, mondrian

In TelCo industry is very important to know what was the customer status at some some point (end of week, month, etc).
So, I have SDC type II dimension with: customer_tk, customerID, status, date.

We use it custom reports to find what is state on some day (example):

Date = '2015-10-01'

```
Group     Active    Terminated     Suspended     Order
------------------------------------------------------
Group1    25        2              2             8
Group2    45        8              0             12
Group3    15        18             5             2
Group4    65        2              1             29
```

This is pivoted from query:

```
SELECT * FROM dim_customer
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(customer_tk) as maxId, customerId FROM dim_customer WHERE date<='2015-10-01' GROUP BY customerId) as maxCust
ON dim_customer.customer_tk = maxCust.maxId
```

And it works perfectly (date is parameter from report).

**I want to put it in cube** but how to create this type of join? **I need cumulative count of customers**

I tried with MDX Tail(filter(... )) expressions but didn't managed to get correct numbers.

So, basically, with no filters, it should return status = 8 for customer 29841 and status = 2 for customer 28425.

[image]

But if choose year = 2014, it should return status = 2 for both customers:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a fuller example script of what you've tried in `mdx`? I'm guessing you have `[status].[status].members on columns` and not too sure about rows, then are you using a `WITH` clause that has calculations using `Tail(filter(... )) `?

Comment: @whytheq I tried WITH MEMBER [Measures].[MyMeasure] as ([Measure].[DistinctCustomers], Tail (Filter([Time].AllMembers, not isEmpty([Measure].[DistinctCustomers]), 1).Item(0))

Comment: @whytheq I also tried WITH MEMBER [Measures].[MyMeasure] as ([Measure].[DistinctCustomers], Tail (Filter([Status].AllMembers, not isEmpty([Measure].[DistinctCustomers]), 1).Item(0)).. Tried to change AllMembers to CurrentMember

Comment: @whytheq Is there any way to find out what is last Status was (before or after slicing), than I will be maybe on better path. Thanks

Comment: this looks a little unusual to me `[Measure].[DistinctCustomers]` ...the word `DistinctCustomers` sounds more like a `SET` rather than a custom measure. Did you try starting your script like this `WITH SET [DistinctCustomers] AS ...` and then feeding this SET into the definition of `[Measures].[MyMeasure] `? Would you be able to add the full script to your question please.

Comment: @whytheq [Measure].[DistinctCustomers] is just count_distinct on customerID, I edited question if it can help you to understand my needs.